# CSS - boostrap btn-group-justified with spacing between buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following example you can see that the buttons are barely indistinguishable from eachother and would therefor want to use some spacing between the buttons like btn-toolbar does. I cant use that however since the buttons will be very small and don't fill the entire div

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the spacing to be like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="group">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution. Since btn-group rounds only far left and right edges of group, you'd rather remove `.btn-group` from `<div class=" btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">`, and then set paddings to inner divs of class `.btn-group`

As you wish you can define higher specificity for this `.btn-group` to prevent a spread of style outside.

```css
.btn-group {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-group-justified" role="group">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap grid system.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
<div class=" btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
<div class=" col-xs-5">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-5">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works but doesnt fill the entire way like i wanted. went with another answer

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like below?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Yes</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, looks just like i wanted, but went with a css answer instead